# asp.net mvc4 controller allow null complex object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

If I have this:

```
public ActionResult BuscarClientes(SomeClass c)
 { ... code ...}
```

And I access the url to this action without any parameter (so I don't give any elements to my model), I still get a newly created object. But, I'm wanting to get a NULL object instead if no arguments are given.

This is because I'm using this method as a search action method, and the first time the get is done I don't want to perform any validation and just return the view. After that, the post will be a GET method (its a search I need to make it a get request) with all the values in the query string.

How can I force the model binder to give me a null object if no parameters are given in the query string? Because as it is now, i get a new instance of SomeClass with all its properties set to null. Instead of just a null object.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope, sadly.

I ended up doing some stuff with redirects and two action methods.

Comment: That's to bad. I ended up using the [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] with the different parameters with a private function that had optional parameters so each ActionResult could call it. (Thanks for the feedback!)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying default value to the parameter

```
public ActionResult BuscarClientes(SomeClass c = null)
    { ... code ...}
```

Comment: I have tried that already but there's no null coming in, always a constructed object, even if my get request has no values on the query string